# BigInt is not supported in React Native

Tags: react-native, bigint

When I use BigInt in RN app I get this error:

```
Can't find variable: BigInt
```

How can I use BigInt in RN project?

Comment: The solution this person posted on github worked for me https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28492#issuecomment-824698934

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by installing the `big-integer` package and implementing a simple polyfill using it:

```
if (typeof BigInt === 'undefined') {
    global.BigInt = require('big-integer');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, React Native doesn't natively support BigInt. However, you can work around this limitation by using a library like big-integer to handle large integers in your React Native project.

Here are the steps to use big-integer in your React Native project:

1. Install the big-integer library in your project. You can do this using npm or yarn:

```
npm install big-integer
# or
yarn add big-integer
```

2. Import and use the big-integer library in your code:

```
import bigInt from 'big-integer';

const a = bigInt('123456789012345678901234567890');
const b = bigInt('987654321098765432109876543210');

const result = a.plus(b);
console.log(result.toString()); // Convert to string for output
```

Comment: I had the same problem in node_modules/reactotron-core-client/serialize.ts and after implementing your solution it worked !but instead of import bigInt from 'big-integer'; updated to import BigInt from 'big-integer';

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this code snippet to your `index.js`, the error will go away.

```
if (global.BigInt === undefined) {
  const bi = require("big-integer");

  // Allow BigInt('0xffffffffffffffff') or BigInt('0x777777777777777777')
  global.BigInt = (value) => {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
      // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-named-capture-group
      const match = value.match(/^0([xo])([0-9a-f]+)$/i);
      if (match) {
        return bi(match[2], match[1].toLowerCase() === "x" ? 16 : 8);
      }
    }
    return bi(value);
  };
}

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```